# Excel VBA: How to sum values in column until value in another column changes?

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying to figure out how I can sum the data in column D until the value in column A changes, and place the result in B. Also, the sum result should only be in rows where there is text in column A. I put an example image of my set-up. I would like to use VBA as some spreadsheets I have in this format have hundreds of line items.

[image]

I imagine I can use VBA to get the row number of the next non blank cell in column A, but I can't quite figure out the code.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: A formula can do this as long as you are okay with the formula being in the blank cells and returning an empty string `""`

Comment: That should work! Any thoughts on how to set that up?